# Nashorn JS Engine. Execute command with space in path

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I'm using the Java Nashorn engine to execute commands via 
`Runtime.getRuntime.exec(...)` like this:

```
var imports = new JavaImporter(java.lang);
with(imports){
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Applications/Some App/Contents/MacOS/Some App");
}
```

The problem ist, that applications or paths with spaces in it are not executed. If the app has no spaces in it, it simply works.

I tried

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Applications/Some\ App/Contents/MacOS/Some\ App");`

and

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Applications/Some\\ App/Contents/MacOS/Some\\ App");`

but nothing worked for me.

Does anyone have a hint for me, what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try quoting the path: `"\"/Applications/Some App/Contents/MacOS/Some App\""`

Comment: Indeed, nice idea - thanks. But sadly it didn't work.